# How do I know whether my sample is fair?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, t-test, sampling

I have a time series dataset with 500 million rows, twenty-six columns and 400 thousand unique actors.

It's too much data for me to process all at once, so I want to take a fair sample of my data.

I'll spend some time talking about the factors:

1. Four of the columns are IDs and the 400K number references the most granular ID
2. Two of the columns are dates, one column for the day we recorded the row and another for the actor's creation date
3. Eight of the columns are numeric variables that cluster around 0-5 and have a long tail up to hundreds
4. Eight of the columns are factors with five or fewer levels. Most of these factors cluster 80% of unique actors into one or two buckets and then split the remaining 20% across the remaining one to three buckets
5. Four of the columns are factors with lots of levels. The most levels for a factor is in the hundreds and the other three have about seventy levels. 80% of the rows can be attributed to the top fifty levels for the most populous factor and top twenty for the other three factors.

My plan is to take a simple random sample of 120 thousand unique actors and filter down my dataset with that sample

I'm concerned that I'll get a sample that's not representative of my population. I'm concerned, in part, because my data becomes extremely sparse with the less popular levels and the long tails for the numerics.

Comment: There are many good solutions to such problems, typically involving forms of probability sampling.  But determining them requires understanding your analytical objectives. Could you clarify those? Also, it might be worth remarking that this isn't a terribly huge database: this morning I processed one with the same number of rows and 42 columns involving around 40 million unique "actors" (or their analog) in `R` using a machine with 64 GB RAM. The technique is to split the input into smaller pieces and, to the extent possible, put the database into 4th normal form using auxiliary tables.

Comment: What technology do you use to run operations on the whole dataset? I tried disk frames and found it lacking in a couple key areas

Comment: I use the `data.table` package, with judicious processing (keeping strings as factors and normalizing the structure) and, initially, by splitting the raw input into pieces, processing them separately, and combining the results.

Comment: Nice, so you make distinct aggregate tables from smaller chunks of the raw input and then you put them together